# How to add array of objects in js?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the sum of 5,10,15
Tried getting the sum like object .a+ object .b+ object .c
But not getting the correct response in jsfiddle

let object =[{a:5},{b:10},{c:15}];

Comment: That's because what you called `object` is actually an _array_. You need to access the items in that array via their index first.

Comment: How to ask a good question on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you're learning JS, don't work on JSfiddle but work on the browser console. Write down your object definition then see when happens when you execute `object[0]`, `object[1]` and so on

Comment: As someone suggested, what you call object is actually an object array, your sum should be `object[0].a+ object[1].b+ object[2].c`, and when your object is `{a: 5,b:10,c:15}`, you can use `object.a+ object.b+ object.c`

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let ar=[{a:5},{b:10},{c:15}];
let sum=0;
  ar.map(res=>{
    sum+=parseInt(Object.values(res));
    })
  console.log(sum)
```

Comment: object[0].a , object[0].b , object[0].c , object[1].a, object[1].b , object[1].c & so on

Comment: Object[0].b undefined. Same for 0 index c.